# How do I remove the blue border on focus?

Tags: react-day-picker

When I click on the day picker component container or an individual cell within the calendar, a blue border gets added.

I couldn't find the related CSS in style.css, nor do I see any classes being added in DevTools that could be adding the blue border.

How do I get rid of this?[image]

Answer (score 6):

The blue "border" gets added when the `DayPicker-wrapper` element gets focused.  It's actually the `outline` css property that generally gets added to any focused element unless you specify otherwise.

To remove the outline from the overall `DayPicker` element, add the following to the `.DayPicker-wrapper` class in your `DayPicker` component [stylesheet](https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/blob/master/src/style.css):

```
.DayPicker-wrapper {
  outline: none;
}
```

You can also remove it from the individual days by adding `{outline: none;}` to the `.DayPicker-Day` class.

Answer (score 5):

Mark's solution works perfectly; just fyi, if you want to remove all outline (blue border) without adding multiple classes, try writing:

```
.DayPicker * {
  outline: none;
}
```